# Doctrine many-to-many join table not populating

Tags: mysql, xml, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the below doctrine `.ORM.XML` files. I've updated the schema and can see all tables and join tables in the database and I can instantiate entities just fine for both <kbd>Product</kbd> and <kbd>Order</kbd>.

**Products.orm.xml:**

```
<entity name="Product" table="product"
        repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository">

    <many-to-many target-entity="Order" inversed-by="Product" field="orders">
        <join-table name="products_orders">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="Product_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="Orders_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>
```

**Orders.orm.xml:**

```
<entity name="Order" table="order"
        repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\OrderRepository">

   <many-to-many field="products" mapped-by="orders" target-entity="Product" />
</entity>
```

However, when I `flush()` an entity to the database it is only being created individually in the <kbd>Product</kbd>/<kbd>Order</kbd> tables and no corresponding key record is being generated in the <kbd>products_orders</kbd> join table as I would have expected. Below is the code I have in my controllers to `flush()` to the database - do I somehow need to expand on this this to deal with the <kbd>products_orders</kbd> join table too?

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\Order;

class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/neworder", name="new_order")
     */
    public function newOrderAction(Request $request)
    {
        $order = new Order();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->findAllOrderedByName();

        $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($order)
            ->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Product',
                'choice_label' => 'Description',
            ))
            ->add('Quantity', 'integer')
            ->add('Units', 'text')
            ->add('Save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Order'))
            ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($order);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:new.order.form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Following Cerad's suggestions, I've added the code for my <kbd>Order</kbd> entity definition below where I have added the `addProduct()` function. I also have added a corresponding `addOrder()` method to my <kbd>Product</kbd> entity code too:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Order
{
    protected $id;
    public $products;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function addProduct($product) {
        $product->addOrder($order);
    }
    #....
}
```

However when I try to update doctrine entities I get an error:

> Compile Error: Cannot redeclare AppBundle\Entity\Order::addProduct

Comment: you must persist product object instead of orders

Comment: Assuming you are populating in right way the products collection, you can check what happening if you add "cascade" directive in many-to-many products node,    http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html#defining-many-to-many-associations

Comment: Thanks @SilvioQ, I added in `<cascade><cascade-all></cascade-all></cascade>` on Products (just before <join-table> section). I wasn't sure whether to add it to the XML for Orders  too it doesn't seem to be right. I've updated the schema and entities but unfortunately the join table is still empty. Is there anything I can update the question with to help identify the issue?

Comment: Verify that your product entity contains a reference to the order entity and vice versa.  It's not uncommon to forget to cross link the two.  If you are not sure then update your question and show the controller code before the handleRequest.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad - I've added my full controller to the end of the question. I'm just going to update it again to add a section of my <kbd>Order</kbd>  entity in case that is what you mentioned I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your Order::addProduct looks like this:

```
class Order {
  addProduct($product) {
    $this->products[] = $product;
```

If so then you are not telling the product about the new order.  You need to add

```
    $product->addOrder($order);
```

That will complete your two way references and should allow persist to work as expected.  If you already have the above code then something else is amiss.

Comment: Thanks I think you're right - although I'm using doctrine generated entities with auto-generated getters/setters. The `addProduct` method you mentioned I don't have at all. Do  I need to add a corresponding `addOrder` method to my Product entity too? I thought I was taking care of that in `__construct`?

Comment: Post the Order code that deals with products.  You should have some sort of add or set product.  Likewise, your Product entity needs some sort of set/add order.  By the way, having a many to many relation between product and order is a bit unusual.  Typically you would have an OrderLine entity which would allow setting a quantity for a given product.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the Order class after trying to add the `addProduct` function you mentioned - along with the doctrine error I'm getting - thanks in advance

Comment: The error message indicates there is already an addProduct method in the Order class.

Comment: Thanks - I did! fixed it now and am getting my "real" error of `Catchable Fatal Error: "Arguement 1 passed ...must be of the type array`. However, in my above code I have it defined as array - does this need to be array in `orm.xml` too somehow?